# Post pictures next to text field PHP

Tags: html, css, forms

I am creating a form page that will post information for a book (author name, title, press, year, etc.) to an SQL database, and then echo that information back onto the page. An image will also be submitted to a Photos directory and then echoed back onto the page. I am having trouble displaying the images next to the text field without moving the text downwards when a new image is posted.

http://aswanson.net/Work/display.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head>
<title>Display</title>
<style>


img{
margin-left: -50%;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.paragraph{
    padding-bottom: 60px;
    width: 300px; 
}

.info{
    margin-top: -40%;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("xxxx","xxxx","xxxx");
mysqli_select_db($con, "xxxx");


$getquery=mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT * FROM historytable ORDER BY id DESC');

echo '<div class = "info">'; 
echo '<div class="pics">';

$images = glob("Photos/*.*");

foreach($images as $image) {
echo '<img src="'.$image.'" /><br />';
}

echo '</div>';
while($rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($getquery))
    {
        $id=$rows['id'];
        $LastName=$rows['LastName'];
        $FirstName=$rows['FirstName'];
        $Year=$rows['Year'];
        $Press=$rows['Press'];
        $Description=$rows['Description'];
        $Title=$rows['Title'];


        echo '<div class = "paragraph">' . $LastName . '<br/>'. $FirstName . '<br/>' . $Year . '<br/>' .  $Press . '<br/>' . $Title . '<br/>'. $Description .  '</div>' ;
    }

    echo '</div>';
?>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Obviously a picture path should be stored in a db.

Comment: Is there another way around this? I followed many tutorials for your suggestion and they didn't work properly.

Comment: So - how do you know which image should be displayed with what text?

Comment: And if tutorials didn't work - you obviously did something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if each image is related to a particular text. But if you want to display text fields beside images regardless of any relation between image and text, add the below css.

```
.pics{
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: When I did that they just display diagonally, going downward. Each image is independent of text, as they are being pulled from a directory, while the text is being pulled from a database.

Comment: can you share the link ?